# How to extract in elegant way the string using the regular expression in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, extract

I have the following script which I'm fetching as text:
http://pastebin.com/c8XHN27N

How can I cut/extract the desired URL from it using a regular expression?

I need to get the next value from the script above:
`t="https://s3.amazonaws.com/s3.maketutorial.com/users/7a75f78cb4644e4188ad82d063b1f54b/settings.txt"`

Comment: Is it a constant string? I have taken a look at your retrieved JavaScript file and it looks like you want to retrieve the value for the key "walkme_custom_user_settings_", is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if this is what you want. But this will help you extract all urls from the script file

```
var src = "...";
var reg = /(\b(https?|ftp):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/gim
var urls = src.match(reg);
console.log(urls);
/* [
    "http://www.walkme.com/",
    "https://localhost/mt/resources/",
    "https://localhost/mt/lib/maketutorial_lib.js",
    "https://d3b3ehuo35wzeh.cloudfront.net",
    "https://s3.amazonaws.com/s3.maketutorial.com/users/7a75f78cb4644e4188ad82d063b1f54b/settings.txt"
] */
```

https://regex101.com/r/aD4lW7/1

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 `t` vars in the script you passed, all with the same value inside, so there is no way to distinguish them.

Then we can pick up the first of the 3 with a simple:

```
script = "...";
tVar = script.match(/t="[^"]*"/)[0] || '';
console.log(tVar); 
// "t="https://s3.amazonaws.com/s3.maketutorial.com/users/7a75f78cb4644e4188ad82d063b1f54b/settings.txt""
```